# How can I save draggable div positions in html

Tags: javascript, html, position, draggable

I'm a newbie in html and javascripts, and trying to save my draggable div positions after clicking save button in my web application. my question is little bit different with others that I'm using Websocket for getting data

Here is my draggable divs which is creating from websocket in javascript code

```
function WebSocket(){
  if ("WebSocket" in window){
    var channel = "hello";
    var socket = io.connect("my socket address here");

    socket.on(channel, function (d) {
      var data = JSON.parse(d);
      console.log(channel + " : " + d);
      var theDiv = document.getElementById(data.node_info[1].info.mac);
      if(theDiv == null) {
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");
        divTag.id = data.node_info[1].info.mac;   //"drag1"
        divTag.className = "draggable js-drag";
        divTag.innerHTML = data.node_info[1].info.mac;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(divTag);
        //document.getElementsByName('scroll_div')[0].appendChild(divTag);
        //$('#'+data.node_info[1].info.mac).load('#'+data.node_info[1].info.mac);
      }
    });
    socket.on('crc_err', function(packet){
      console.log("crc_err : " + packet);
    });
    socket.on('type_err', function(packet){
      console.log("type_err : " + packet);
    });
  } else{
    // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
    // alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}
```

I created divTags with `id, className, innerHTML` and each of them shows mac addresses and put them in the body of html.

Also, I want those draggable divs is positioned in same places as last time when users revisit my web app.

How should I do and any suggestions here??

Thanks in advance.

p.s If you need my css code or more code of html I can **EDIT**

Comment: You can save the div top and left position in local storage

Comment: To persist any information longer than the life of the browser or the connection to your socket requires the use of a database. Another option could be cookies but this would require the user to access the page from the same machine and browser. It is popular to use MongoDB if hosting on your web sockets on a node server.

Comment: Sun Vs mentioned local storage. This will work only if you do not need the values saved passed the use of the browser session. Aka, once the user closes Chrome (or any other browser) this data is lost forever.

Comment: @Matt i think you are confusing localStorage with sessionStorage.

Comment: @AliKazmi Then it means doesn't lose forever even if the user closes the browser?

Comment: @paulc1111 yes, data saved in localStorage is not cleared when closing the browser.

Comment: @paulc1111 take a look at http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/09/08/getting-started-with-localstorage-vs-sessionstorage-in-html5/

Comment: @AliKazmi oh I see, then if the user uses different browser like IE or firefox or etc, then it will reset everything right?

Comment: I was incorrect, sessionStorage is what I was describing. Here is a link to a description of both. There are limits to localStorage that should be considered. www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @paulc1111 that is correct, if that's your use case, you'll have to store the position data on your server and load it back from there

Comment: @AliKazmi oh I see, I was trying to use json file to save position.. Am I on the right way?

Comment: @paulc1111 should be sufficient for very light user load, but ideally you should store this in a database table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use localStorage**

**To save**

```
localStorage.setItem(divTag.id + '-X', leftPosition);
localStorage.setItem(divTag.id + '-Y', topPosition);
```

**To load back**

```
divTag.style.left = localStorage.getItem(divTag.id + '-X') + 'px';
divTag.style.top = localStorage.getItem(divTag.id + '-Y') + 'px';
```